# How to count all subfolders in a group of folders via batch? (NOT files!)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a group of folders, let's say 1000+. Every folder has a *random* name and from 2 to 300 subfolders inside it. I'd wanted to count these sub-folders, and echo them to the output file the way like this:

```
"Folder 1 - 22 subfolders
Folder 2 - 5 subfolders
Folder 3 - 16 subfolders
folder 4 - 198 subfolders
...
folder 1000 - 3 subfolders"
```

But I'm so confused with this BATCH syntax that is completely unreadable. Here's what I've tried:

```
for /d %%a in (*) do (      :: for /d(irectory) %%a in (set of folders with any name available) do (
    echo %%a>>output.txt    :: first "echo" the name of the folder into output.txt
    for /s %%b in (%%a) do  :: then do internal for to list throughout the sub-folders: /s should have meant /s(ubdirectories), %%b is the second variable to list the subdirectories itself, %%a should have meant the name of the current folder (Folder 1, Folder 2, Folder 3 etc.) or path to it, doesn't really matter
        count = count+1   ::increase count number by 1
        echo %count%>>output.txt ::echo counted value into output.txt
```

not working at all

```
for /d %%a in ('dir /b /s %folder%^|find /c /v ""') do set count=%%a echo %count% folder(s^)>> output.txt
```

echoing the common number of sub-folders, not divided into different folders.

What am I doing wrong? How could I accomplish my task?

Comment: The *"unreadable BATCH syntax"* is just wrong. Type each command followed by `/?` into a Command Prompt window to learn the correct syntax. There is no `/S` option of `for`, for example. Furthermore, please explain what yo want to count: is it the number of immediate sub-folders per folder of the *"group of folders"*, or so you also want to recurse into the sub-folder tree as well?

Comment: Move your counting code to procedure. Then call it for each group's folder.

Answer (score 1):

You're close, but some details are not correct.

- Since you are working with variables inside a loop, you need `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion`, and reference those variables as `!MYVARIABLE!`
- To do a mathematical calculation, use `SET /A`
- The inner loop should also have the `/d` switch, since you are dealing with directories
- Use braces `()` in the inner loop
- Initialize the count variable as 0
- A closing brace `)` for the outer loop is missing

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /d %%a in (*) do (
    set count=0
    for /d %%b in ("%%a\*") do (
        set /a count += 1
    )
    echo %%a - !count! subfolders>> output.txt
)
```